# Pyplot annotation: roman numerals

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, latex

In a python plot, I would like to put annotations in with Roman numerals. I.e., "I", "II", "III" and "IV".

Now, the straightforward thing to do is to simply use strings as "I", "II", etc., but I would like them to be typeset specifically as Roman numerals (so, including the horizontal bar on top and below of the III, for instance.

The difficulty is mainly that using LateX commands, as I would do for other symbols (e.g. \alpha), doesn't seem possible because if one wants to use Roman numerals in LateX it is common practice to define [a new command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23487/how-can-i-get-roman-numerals-in-text) and I wouldn't know how to incorporate that within the python environment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, by placing your LaTeX `\newcommand` in the `text.latex.preamble` in [`plt.rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html). Here I use the command for Roman Numerals from the [answer you linked to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23487/how-can-i-get-roman-numerals-in-text). To help with the escaping of LaTeX characters, we can use raw strings to make thing easier (preface the string with the `r` character).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Turn on LaTeX formatting for text    
plt.rcParams['text.usetex']=True

# Place the command in the text.latex.preamble using rcParams
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=r'\makeatletter \newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@} \makeatother'

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Lets try it out. Need to use a 'raw' string to escape 
# the LaTeX command properly (preface string with r)
ax.text(0.2,0.2,r'\rom{28}')

# And to use a variable as the roman numeral, you need 
# to use double braces inside the LaTeX braces:
for i in range(1,10):
    ax.text(0.5,float(i)/10.,r'\rom{{{}}}'.format(i))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Your example doesn't work for me however. When I copy your working example, I obtain the same figure but instead of the roman numerals, \rom{1}, \rom{2} et cetera..

Comment: Ah, it looks like I have something in my `matplotlibrc` that you don't. Try adding `plt.rcParams['text.usetex']=True` before the other `rcParams` line (see my edit above)